# Reference secrets from base in overlay

Tags: kustomize

Is there any way in Kustomize to reference a secret, which has been generated and is used in my base, to another resource (e.g. Deployment or StatefulSet) in my overlay? I face the problem, that all occurences of the secrets name are replaced by the hashed name only in the base and not in my overlay.

I guess that there is now way around this problem, but maybe someone has a hint for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right that's one of the limitations of the generators (both Secret and ConfigMap): They can only update resources included in their `kustomization.yml` file. By the way it works even if the resources included themselves include other resources.
For example, having a `base`, `overlayA` that include the `base` and `overlayB` that includes `overlayA`:

- any secret generated in the `base` will update its references on any resources created by the `base`
- any secret generated in `overlayA` will update references in resources created in `overlayA` and `base`
- finally any secret generated in `overlayB` will update references in `base`, `overlayA` and `overlayB`

Personally, I try to keep all my secrets in the "highest" overlay, since in general they might need to be passed across overlays and are environment dependent anyway.